# How could I handle the datetime for high frequency time series prediction (based on seconds)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, time-series, data-science

How could I handle the datetime data for high frequency time series prediction (predict the value of next 2 seconds)?

I am working on time series data for predicting the value of next 2 seconds. The data time column is originally timestamp type and I have converted to datetime type with

```
pd.to_datetime(data.time,unit='us')
```

How could I change the followed date format to seconds for prediction? Any advice on model selection for high frequency time series prediction?

```
2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390   low
2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390    low
2020-01-12 15:12:20.500599    medium
2020-01-12 15:12:21.501825    high
2020-01-12 15:12:22.501052    .... 
2020-01-12 15:12:23.500284      
2020-01-12 15:12:24.501484    ...
```

Comment: What is your expect result?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I hope the expected result is: when the new data come in, I could make prediction for the next second value. e.g 2022-01-03 10:12:23  value is: high

Answer (score 1):

you can use Prophet for this purpose

```
df =pd.to_datetime(data.time,unit='us')
```

ad following

```
m = Prophet(changepoint_prior_scale=0.01).fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=300, freq='H')
fcst = m.predict(future)
fig = m.plot(fcst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Coerce date to datetime, extract the time component and convert it to a timedelta element to get total seconds. Code below

```
df['seconds']=pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")).astype('timedelta64[s]')

      

    datetime                  seconds
0  2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  54740.0
1  2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  54740.0
2  2020-01-12 15:12:20.500599  54740.0
3  2020-01-12 15:12:21.501825  54741.0
4  2020-01-12 15:12:22.501052  54742.0
5  2020-01-12 15:12:23.500284  54743.0
6  2020-01-12 15:12:24.501484  54744.0
```

If you need microsecond resolution to predict seconds you could try

```
df['micrseconds']=pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")).astype('timedelta64[ms]')

       datetime                 microseconds
0  2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  54740354.0
1  2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  54740354.0
2  2020-01-12 15:12:20.500599  54740500.0
3  2020-01-12 15:12:21.501825  54741501.0
4  2020-01-12 15:12:22.501052  54742501.0
5  2020-01-12 15:12:23.500284  54743500.0
6  2020-01-12 15:12:24.501484  54744501.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for:

```
df['time2'] = df['time'].to_numpy().astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
                        time                time2
0 2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  1578841940354390000
1 2020-01-12 15:12:20.354390  1578841940354390000
2 2020-01-12 15:12:20.500599  1578841940500599000
3 2020-01-12 15:12:21.501825  1578841941501825000
4 2020-01-12 15:12:22.501052  1578841942501052000
5 2020-01-12 15:12:23.500284  1578841943500284000
6 2020-01-12 15:12:24.501484  1578841944501484000
```

Comment: Do you mean I should make the time interval based on the timestamp ( 2 seconds interval):  1578841940354390000, 1578841942501052000, 1578841944501484000.....? thanks